# React Native WebView allow one domain

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I have a simple webview,see below;

```
<WebView
            source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/',
                headers: {
                    Cookie: 'cookies=dismiss; ui=darkmode',
                },
            }}
            originWhitelist={['https://*']}
            allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
            pullToRefreshEnabled={true}
            sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
            geolocationEnabled={true}

        />
```

Now with inside my webview people can have profiles and links to third-party websites, how do I make those links to use an external web browser or expo web browser instead of loading them in my webview.

Using expo for the project.

Answer (score 1):

**if that url differs from the original domain, stops the loading, preventing page change, and opens it in the OS Navigator instead.**

```
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

const webviewRef = useRef(null);

<WebView
        ref={webviewRef}
        source={{ uri : 'https://example.com/' }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
          if (!event.url.includes("example.com")) {
            webviewRef.stopLoading();
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
          }
        }}
      />
```

Comment: looks legit, upvoted :)

Comment: Does not work show error under this.webview.stopLoading(); then proceeds to load third-party URL inside the webview.

Comment: check webviewRef.stopLoading(); i have updated the answer

Comment: Hey, I don't know if this is too late, but you need to use current when using useRef, that's why probably didn't work for you. `webviewRef.current.stopLoading()`